# jQuery.get() returning error

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery, get

I'm new to javascript/jquery.

I have the following basic code and I keep receiving the "error" alert message:

```
var jqxhr = $.get('my_url',
                function(data) {
                alert("success");
            })

            .success(function() {
                alert("second success");
            })
            .error(function() {
                alert("error");
            })
            .complete(function() {
                alert("complete");
            });
```

Note that if I copy and paste `my_url` in the browser I get an xml file back. What am I doing wrong? How can I get a detailed error description??

Comment: Use your browser's console and its network tab.

Comment: Just to confirm, `my_url` is **not** a variable, correct?

Comment: Use Firebugs 'net'  tab to see what is being sent and received.

Comment: Is my_url on the same domain as your web page?  If not, you will be restricted by the [same-origin-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Or ctrl-shift-J and the network tab in chrome.

Comment: @KevinB my_url is an actual url and not a variable. If a copy/paste my_url in a browser I get the xml.

Comment: @izb ctrl-shift-J is pretty useful, this is what I got: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'my_url'. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: @jfriend00 is this related to what you are talking about: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'my_url'. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` ?

Comment: Yes, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a same origin issue.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, how do I fix this? Basically my page wants to go and get some data from a public API on another domain...

Comment: I've posted an answer with more description of the issue and a possible work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'my_url'. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

indicates that you have a same origin issue.  You cannot do ajax calls to a domain that is different than the domain of the host web page.

See [this MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) for more info on same origin on the same origin policy.

A work-around is to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (which uses script tags which are not subject to the same origin policy), but this requires changing the server to support JSONP for this operation.

Answer (score 1):

did you change the response type to 'text/xml' in the $.ajaxSettings() function?

if you are expecting 'text/html' as a response type  and getting 'text/xml' then this could cause a problem.

also if you use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) you can get a good idea of what is actually goin on in the response.

Comment: Thanks Qpirate, I figured out what the issue is by using Chrome's `ctrl-shift-J`. There are more information in the comments, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: i would use the JSONP to do the cross domain call. as @jfriend00 mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

There are really only three ways to fix a cross-origin issue.

1. Make the remote server support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
2. User a proxy script or proxy service such as [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)
3. Use the jsonp datatype which does support cross-origin requests. This solution requires that the server returns JSONP instead of XML